# Building a product page with gallery using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm helping a client build a product site, one of the pages displays the details of the products their selling. One of the requirements of the product detail page is to have multiple images of the product (which I'm fine with, going to implement a slider) however the product images will also be in different colours. Depending on the colour the user selects the relevant product images are shown. I'm having trouble with how implement the colour select option.

I am using BX-Slider (http://bxslider.com/) on another page so would like to be able to reuse the same slider. Anyone give me any pointers?

I've included the design of the product page here:

[image]

Would much appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used bxslider, but it looks like you could use this to your advantage:

http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors

If you create custom prev/next selectors then you can create an index, so that you know which colour is currently selected in the slider and then display the corresponding image. With the custom selectors, this would be done in the `JQuery.click()` functions of the two spans (in the example).

```
$("#slider-next").click(...change image to index + 1...);
$("#slider-prev").click(...change image to index - 1...);
```